# how to get the hour time?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on my python script to get the 12 hours time.

I want to get the `7` hour instead of `07`.

```
self.getControl(4203).setLabel(time.strftime("%I") + ':30' + 
time.strftime("%p"))
print (time.strftime("%I"))
```

Here is the log:

```
19:41:47 T:5288  NOTICE: 07
```

Can you please tell me how I can get the hour time `7` instead of `07`?

Comment: `%l` will work on Linux but I don't think that's portable.

Comment: pass it through int: `int('07')` -> `7`

Comment: (actually lstrip is faster and clearer if you want the result as a string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Derek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24639648/189134) mentions in his answer, you can strip leading zeros for a more portable solution.

```
>>> print(time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0'))
2
```

If you are on a Linux platform that uses glibc though, you have a few additional options.

#### Option 1:

Use `%l`. Notice that this leaves has a space at the beginning, in place of the `0`:

```
>>> print(time.strftime("%l"))
 2
```

#### Option 2:

Use `%-I`. This does not have the leading `0` or leading space.

```
>>> print(time.strftime("%-I"))
2
```

These two options work on Linux systems that use glibc, because Python uses the [`strftime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) from that library.

Answer (score 2):

You can use lstrip to remove a given character from the left side of the result (if it exists):

```
hour = time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0')
print(hour)
```

Comment: +1, but only because %I never returns 00 (which %H does). I would rather use %l and `lstrip(' ')` just to be sure it still works when 24h mode is used (%k)